# Is taking the SAT ueful when when applying for a graduate degree in South Korea?

Tags: graduate-admissions, exams, south-korea

I'm studying computer engineering and I want to do my graduate studies in South Korea.

Is taking the SAT to prove my math and English skills helpful for my application?

Comment: Why not take GRE ?

Comment: Isn't SAT more for undergraduateb admission?